# How to convert comma separated strings enclosed within bracket to array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

How to convert below string to array in Javascript? The reason is that I want to take both value separately.
The string is value from an element, when I print it to console I got:('UYHN7687YTF09IIK762220G6','Second')

```
var data = elm.value;
console.log(data);
```

Comment: You want to convert it into ('UYHN7687YTF09IIK762220G6','Second') to ["U", "Y", "H", "N", "7", "6", "8", "7", "Y", "T", "F", "0", "9", "I", "I", "K", "7", "6", "2", "2", "2", "0", "G", "6"]

Provide details and write some code so that community will help rather than just asking answer

Comment: @Umashankar into array ['UYHN7687YTF09IIK762220G6','Second']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with `regex`, like this for example :

```js
const string = "('UYHN7687YTF09IIK762220G6','Second')";
const regex = /'(.*?)'/ig

// Long way
const array = [];
let match;
while (match = regex.exec(string)){
  array.push(match[1]);
};
console.log(array)

// Fast way
console.log([...string.matchAll(regex)].map(i => i[1]))
```

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/split)

Answer (score 0):

```
let given_string = "('UYHN7687YTF09IIK762220G6','Second')";

// first remove the both ()
given_string = given_string.substring(1); // remove (
given_string = given_string.substring(0, given_string.length - 1); // remove )

let expected_array = given_string.split(',');
console.log(expected_array);
```